# How to map collections to mongodb using datanucleus/jdo?

Tags: mongodb, jdo, foreign-key-relationship, datanucleus

I'm trying to map an existing mongodb database to domain objects using datanuclues (3.0.0-m6) / JDO.

The db has documents like:

```
collection A: {_id: ..., field1: ...}
collection B: {_id: ..., a: ..., field3: ...}
```

That should be mapped to:

```
class A {
    // id ....
    String field1;
    List<B> bs;
}

class B {
    A a;
    Double field3;
}
```

This looks like a [1-N Bidirectional relation using Foreign-Key](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/orm/one_to_many_list.html#fk_bi) as described in the datanuclues documentation.

The package.jdo:

```
<package name="my.domain">
      <class name="A" table="A" identity-type="application">
        <field name="id" primary-key="true"/>
        <field name="bs" persistence-modifier="persistent" mapped-by="a">
            <collection element-type="my.domain.B" />
            <element column="a"/>
        </field>
    </class>
    <class name="B" table="B" identity-type="datastore" >
        <datastore-identity strategy="identity" />
        <field name="a" persistence-modifier="persistent">
            <column name="a"/>
        </field>
    </class>
</package>
```

This works as expected when using a relational DB (e.g. Derby). However, when using mongodb datanucleus uses a collection in the A document containing the ids of the linked Bs:

```
collection A: {_id: ..., field1: ..., bs: [...]}
```

which is not compatible with the existing schema.

How to I configure this kind of relation for mongodb?
Datanucleus distinguishes Set and List for relations (I tested both), a Set might be acceptable if this would make the mapping easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current DataNucleus 1-N behaviour is all that we support ... i.e put the child ids in the parent. The doc you refer to is "ORM", and MongoDB is not relational (so doesn't have "foreign keys" as such anyway). Obviously you could raise a JIRA to add support for that mode, and also attach a patch to provide it.

Comment: OK. MongoDB has a [reference mechanism](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References) that could be used as "foreign key". While such kind of linking might be uncommon for document databases, I think it makes sense in some cases and might be necessary to work with an existing  "schema". Hence, I think this would be a valuable feature.

Comment: I think he was being little bit sarcastic especially because of this '... and also attach a patch to provide it'. MongoDB is by design not relational so any sort of N-N or N-1 relation you should to program out in the client code.

Comment: Use of the MongoDB reference mechanism is a possible extension, sure. And no, nobody was being sarcastic; open source is very simple ... it allows people to contribute extensions should they wish to.